# Python code to webscrape greyhound resukts from gbgb site for soecified dte range

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to use Python code to web scrape all the results for a specific track and I was wondering whether someone knows the best way to do this. I am getting the results from gbgb website but have to enter each meeting ID  and race ID one at a very time-consuming time. I have the following code

```
import httpx
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from  datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ndjson



URLs = [
    
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/398779?raceId=952104", #1st Jul Sat
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/398866?raceId=952458", #4th Jul Tue
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/398899?raceId=952825", #5th Jul Wed
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/398939?raceId=953176", #6th Jul Thu
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/398977?raceId=953593", #7th Jul Fri
   
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/398828?raceId=953127", #8th Jul Sat
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399151?raceId=954378", #11th Jul Tue
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399176?raceId=954701", #12th Jul Wed
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399220?raceId=955255", #13th Jul Thu
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399254?raceId=955557", #14th Jul Fri
   
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399219?raceId=955215", #15th Jul Sat
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399393?raceId=956337", #18th Jul Tue
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399412?raceId=956660", #19th Jul Wed
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399457?raceId=957188", #20th Jul Thu
   "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/399490?raceId=957510", #21th Jul Fri
   
json_list = []
for url in URLs:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    page_context = resp.text
    print(page_context)
    json_file = json.loads(page_context)
    json_list.extend(json_file)
with open('Hove_results.json', 'w') as f:
    ndjson.dump(json_list, f)
```

and race ID and as you can see I have to enter each URL line by line for each day to the Brighton & Hove meeting.

I was wondering whether there is a way to scrape the gbgb website to return all the results for a specific track
The above code pulls the data for specific meeting .

I know there is the follwoing url
https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results?page=1&itemsPerPage=2for a spe00&date=2022-04-12&race_type=race
which will return all the reults for the specific day but what i want if there s a way to specify the range of dates and also have no limite on

Comment: There's no way for us to know this.  You would need to check the documentation for their API.  Since there IS an API, there must be a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Clarification to what I've done below:
> I took the URL syntax provided in your question https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results?page=1&itemsPerPage=2&date=2022-04-12&race_type=race (confirming also with the image provided in gbgb API's github schema diagram) and used that information to break apart and then re build the http link specifying which date ranges to loop through, since it follows a set pattern. You can review the schema here: https://github.com/pipprojects/Greyhounds/blob/master/Schemas/Diagram.png.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import json

json_list = []

base_url = "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results"
params = {
    'page': '1',
    'itemsPerPage': '200',
    'race_type': 'race'
}

# Loop over a range of months and days. Change the number in range to reflect 
# days from 1-X that you want to scrape. 
for month in range(10, 12 + 1):  # this will loop through each month
    get_days_in_month = 28 if month == 2 else (30 if month in [4, 6, 9, 11] else 31)

    for day in range(1, get_days_in_month + 1):  # remember to add +1 to range
        #The date param updates with range changes
        params['date'] = f'2023-{month:02d}-{day:02d}'  # Formats month and day as 2-digit numbers

        try:
            # Use requests to make the HTTP GET request with the parameters
            response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Checks if the request was successful

            page_context_dict = response.json()  # Converts response to dictionary
            items = page_context_dict['items']

            # At this point you can specify what you want to load from the page context
            # into the json file. You suggested you wanted only information specific to
            # a race track. Here's how you can do that:
            specific_track_items = []

            desired_track = "Swindon"
            for item in items:
                if "trackName" in item and item["trackName"] == desired_track:
                    specific_track_items.append(item)

            # Extend the json_list with the actual list of items
            json_list.extend(specific_track_items)

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            print(f"HTTP Error: {errh}")
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print(f"Error Connecting: {errc}")
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print(f"Timeout Error: {errt}")
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print(f"Oops: Something Else: {err}")
        except json.JSONDecodeError as json_err:
            print(f"JSON Decode Error: {json_err}")

# Write the entire json_list to file after the loop
with open('Hove_results.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_list, f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this seems to have worked

Comment: Just a quick follow up is there a way I can loop all the months and days so goes through every month from July onwards every day until end of December rather than changing the dates every time manually

Comment: Hey I added in that functionality to the code. I also noticed an error in my code which is that I forgot the range does not include the last number in the loop, so I added +1 to each range (month and day) as well as accounted for the varying days of each month. Additionally put in a bit of error handling, if you like my answer please give it an upvote if/when you can, it will help me build my reputation here :)